# When trying to print Datatable-button in metronic, I only see my data binding and not my real data

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-repeat, metronic

I am working with Spring with Angularjs and Metronic template and I have issue in the print buttons for datatables-buttons  I am trying to print a datatable that is filled with some data from my MYSQL DataBase, but when I see what is going to be printed I only see that below:
[not wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8KNE.png)

here is my View Code:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
                            <div class="portlet light bordered">
                                <div class="portlet-title">
                                    <div class="caption font-dark">
                                        <i class="icon-settings font-dark"></i>
                                        <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">Buttons</span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tools"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="portlet-body">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Id_client</th>
                                                <th>Nom</th>
                                                <th>prenom</th>
                                                <th>email</th>
                                                <th>adress</th>
                                                <th>Telephone</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody >

                                        <tr data-ng-repeat=" i in pageClient track by i.id_client"  >
                                                <td >{{i.id_client}}</td>
                                                <td >{{i.nom}}</td>
                                                <td >{{i.prenom}}</td>
                                                <td >{{i.email}}</td>
                                                <td >{{i.adresse}}</td>
                                                <td >{{i.telephone}}</td>
                                           </tr>


                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- BEGIN DATATABLE PLUGINS -->
        <script src="../assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
        <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="../assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="../assets/pages/scripts/table-datatables-buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="../angularjs/ng-csv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- BEGIN DATABALES PLUGINS -->
```

and here is my app.js Controller:

```
app.controller("ClientController", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.pageClient = null;
    $http.get("http://localhost:8081/listeClient")
    /* Success */
    .then(function(response) {

        $scope.pageClient = response.data;




    }).catch(function (data) {

    }).finally(function () {

    });

});
```

Every thing is working fine so I am wondering why do i see 
{{i.id_client}} instead if my actual data :[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP4aG.png)